# General strategy to handle reverting financial transactions in DB?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I am building a home budget app with NextJS + Prisma ORM + PostgreSQL.

I am not sure if my current strategy of how to handle deleting/reverting past transactions makes sense in terms of scaling up/db performance..

So, app functions in this way:

1. User adds transaction that are assigned to a chosen bank account. Every transaction row in db includes fields like `amount`, `balanceBefore` and `balanceAfter`.
2. After successful transaction, banks account current balance is being updated.

Now, assuming the situation where multiple transactions has been inserted and user realises he made a mistake somewhere along the line. He would then need to select the transaction and delete/update it, which would follow updating every row following this transaction to update `balanceAfter` and `balanceBefore` fields so the transactions history is correct.

Is there a better way of handling this kind of situation? Having to update a row that is couple thousand records in past might be heavy on resources.

Comment: As a general idea, in banking and accounting, if a charge/debit/transaction was performed it is **never** removed. Upon request the app can produce extra *compensating* transactions to restore balances back to normal. In short, it always "moves forward" and never deletes anything.

Comment: Again generally, balances are kept separate from transactions.  Any book on accounting should provide a guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only should you **never delete or update** a financial transaction but neither should your input data contain balances (before or after). Instead of updating or deleting a transaction you generate 2 new ones: one which reverses the incorrect transaction (thus restoring balances) and one that inserts the correct values.  
As for balances, **do not store them**, just store the transaction amount. Then create a `view` which calculates the balances on the fly when needed. By creating a view you do not need to perform any calculations when DML is preformed on your transactions. See the following [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=562d35994fbde8800) for both the above.